# Round Second with Lubridate

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

[image: data screenshot]

I'm using R, I need to round the seconds referring to the hours 09:14:59 to 09:15:00 I have several records like this.

I tried to use the round_date from the lubridate package

```
temperature = worksheet_temperature %>%
  mutate(measurement_date = round_date(measurement_date, unit=second(as_datetime(as_date(measurement_date, origin = "1899-12-30")))))
```

but I get the following error:

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `measurement_date`.
i `measurement_date = round_date(...)`.
x Invalid period name: 4
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
In addition: Warning message:
Problem with `mutate()` column `measurement_date`.
i `measurement_date = round_date(...)`.
i Unit argument longer than 1. Taking first element
```

how can i solve this?

Comment: Please don't share data as images - it makes it much harder for people to help. Can you please edit your question to include a sample of the data using `dput()` instead?

Comment: Hi Francisco, can you clarify what you want it to be rounded to?

Comment: Mark, I need to round the times that have "59" in seconds. Example: round 09:14:59 to 09:15:00 round 08:32:59 to 08:33:00... did you see the image I posted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description "round the seconds... 09:14:59 to 09:15:00" I assume you are wanting to round to the nearest minute. This is how you can do this:

```r
df <- structure(list(measurement_date = c("2022-02-18 09:14:59", "2022-02-19 08:29:59", 
"2022-02-20 16:40:00", "2022-02-21 09:00:00", "2022-02-22 09:04:59", 
"2022-02-23 09:59:59", "2022-02-24 10:15:00", "2022-02-25 08:35:59", 
"2022-02-26 09:30:00", "2022-02-27 15:00:00", "2022-02-28 08:32:59", 
"2022-03-01 09:35:00", "2022-01-19 08:26:59")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-13L))

library(tidyverse)

mutate(df, measurement_date = round_date(as_datetime(measurement_date), unit = "minute"))

# Output:
      measurement_date
1  2022-02-18 09:15:00
2  2022-02-19 08:30:00
3  2022-02-20 16:40:00
4  2022-02-21 09:00:00
5  2022-02-22 09:05:00
6  2022-02-23 10:00:00
7  2022-02-24 10:15:00
8  2022-02-25 08:36:00
9  2022-02-26 09:30:00
10 2022-02-27 15:00:00
11 2022-02-28 08:33:00
12 2022-03-01 09:35:00
13 2022-01-19 08:27:00
```

There are a variety of other ways of rounding datetimes though. [See the documentation for `round_date` here.](https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/reference/round_date.html)

Answer (score 2):

From your explanation of what the output should look like, you want to round to the nearest minute. In the `unit` argument of `round_date()` simply specify `"minute"`:

```r
lubridate::round_date(
  lubridate::ymd_hms("2022-02-18 09:14:59"),
  unit = "minute"
)
```

this returns: `"2022-02-18 09:15:00 UTC"`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have all the dates rounded up to the nearest boundary, you can use `ceiling_date()`. See [r4ds](https://r4ds.hadley.nz/datetimes.html#rounding).

```
df <- structure(list(measurement_date = c(
  "2022-02-18 09:14:59", "2022-02-19 08:29:59",
  "2022-02-20 16:40:00", "2022-02-21 09:00:00", "2022-02-22 09:04:59",
  "2022-02-23 09:59:59", "2022-02-24 10:15:00", "2022-02-25 08:35:59",
  "2022-02-26 09:30:00", "2022-02-27 15:00:00", "2022-02-28 08:32:59",
  "2022-03-01 09:35:00", "2022-01-19 08:26:59"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(
  NA,
  -13L
))

library(tidyverse)

df |>
  mutate(measurement_date_rounded = ceiling_date(
    x = ymd_hms(measurement_date),
    unit = "minute"
  ))
#>       measurement_date measurement_date_rounded
#> 1  2022-02-18 09:14:59      2022-02-18 09:15:00
#> 2  2022-02-19 08:29:59      2022-02-19 08:30:00
#> 3  2022-02-20 16:40:00      2022-02-20 16:40:00
#> 4  2022-02-21 09:00:00      2022-02-21 09:00:00
#> 5  2022-02-22 09:04:59      2022-02-22 09:05:00
#> 6  2022-02-23 09:59:59      2022-02-23 10:00:00
#> 7  2022-02-24 10:15:00      2022-02-24 10:15:00
#> 8  2022-02-25 08:35:59      2022-02-25 08:36:00
#> 9  2022-02-26 09:30:00      2022-02-26 09:30:00
#> 10 2022-02-27 15:00:00      2022-02-27 15:00:00
#> 11 2022-02-28 08:32:59      2022-02-28 08:33:00
#> 12 2022-03-01 09:35:00      2022-03-01 09:35:00
#> 13 2022-01-19 08:26:59      2022-01-19 08:27:00
```